# Dithering artifacts in Unity 2D game on mobile device

Tags: unity-game-engine, dithering

Dithering can be used to show users a color that is really not there. It also helps to reduce color banding.

I took a screenshot of my unity game on my Android mobile device, zoomed-in the PNG in Photoshop. I observed that the **whole image** (even the solid color areas) is covered with a subtle pixel pattern. Unity Play-mode does not have this effect, only on the mobile device.

**A** - A portion of the game screen at actual size
**B** - Zoomed-in
**C** - Contrast increased to show the subtle pattern

Unity offers [post-processing dithering](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-Dithering.html) in their Post Processing Stack. But this is not it. I don't think Unity is using this to mimic colors because the frames are rendered in a 24-bit color space (to my knowledge). I checked few other commercial mobile games, they don't have this pattern anywhere.

I want to know what is the purpose of this pixel pattern. Thank you.

[image: My Observation On Unity Frame]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the texture's import settings?

Comment: This is not only visible on sprites, textures. Even the solid color (rgb) camera background has this pattern.

Comment: Weird. Not sure what's causing it.